# PySide: redirect stdout to a dialog

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, stdout, pyside

I have a pyside application which runs a function in a QThread. This function often uses `print`. How can I redirect the stdout to a dialog (containing a `qtextedit` or similar) which will display when the function is run.

Here is a minimal example:

```
class Main(QtGui.QWindow):
  def __init__(self):
      super(Main, self).__init__()
      self.run_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Run")

      mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
      mainLayout.addWidget(self.run_button)
      self.setLayout(mainLayout)

      self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.run_event)


  def run_event(self):
      # Create the dialog to display output
      self.viewer = OutputDialog()

      # Create the worker and put it in a thread
      self.worker = Worker()
      self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
      self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
      self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
      self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)

      self.thread.start()


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
  finished = QtCore.Signal()

  def run(self):
    for i in range(10):
      print "Im doing stuff" 
      time.sleep(1)
    self.finished.emit()


class OutputDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):

    super(OutputDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    self.text_edit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.text_edit)

    self.setLayout(vbox)
```

I can modify the worker to redirect stdout to itself, and then emit the text as a signal:

```
class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
  finished = QtCore.Signal()
  message = QtCore.Signal(str)

 def __init__(self):
   super(Worker, self).__init__()

   sys.stdout = self

 def run(self):
    for i in range(10):
      print "Im doing stuff" 
      time.sleep(1)
    self.finished.emit()


 def write(self, text):
     self.message.emit(text)
```

But when I connect this signal to the `OutputDialog` instance, the text is only displayed once the worker has finished.

I have also tried implementing the method here:
[Redirecting stdout and stderr to a PyQt4 QTextEdit from a secondary thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071448/redirecting-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-pyqt4-qtextedit-from-a-secondary-thread?lq=1)

But it just causes my app to freeze.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm surprised you couldn't get the method in "Redirecting stdout and stderr to a PyQt4 QTextEdit from a secondary thread" to work. The example code I provided in my answer there still runs for me. Anyway, Hopefully me answer to this question solves the problem with your current method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this can be done easily by subclassing `QThread`:

```
class Main(QtGui.QWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Main, self).__init__()
    self.run_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Run")

    mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.run_button)
    self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.run_event)

  def run_event(self):
    # Create the dialog to display output
    self.viewer = OutputDialog()

    # Create the worker thread and run it
    self.thread = WorkerThread()
    self.thread.message.connect(self.viewer.write)
    self.thread.start()

class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
  message = QtCore.Signal(str)   

  def run(self):    
    sys.stdout = self


    for i in range(10):
      print "Im doing stuff"
      time.sleep(1)    

  def write(self, text):
    self.message.emit(text)
```

However, most documentation on the web seems to recommend that you do not subclass QThread and instead use the `moveToThread` function for processing tasks.

Also, I don't know how you would distinguish between `stdout` and `stderr` in the above method (assuming that you redirect both to the workerthread)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your print lines only show up once the worker has finished is explained by this stack overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818401/1994235

To summarise, when dealing with signals/slots across threads, you need to decorate the slots with [`@pyqtslot(types)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtSlot) to make sure they are actually run in the thread you intended.