# PyQt4 Wait in thread for user input from GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a thread class "MyThread" and my main application which is simply called "Gui". I want to create a few objects from the thread class but for this example I created only one object. The thread class does some work, then emits a signal to the Gui class, indicating that a user input is needed (this indication for now is simply changing the text of a button). Then the thread should wait for a user input (in this case a button click) and then continue doing what it is doing...

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
class MyTrhead(QtCore.QThread):
    trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        print(self.currentThreadId())
        for i in range(0,10):
            print("working ")
            self.trigger.emit("3 + {} = ?".format(i))
            #### WAIT FOR RESULT
            time.sleep(1)


class Gui(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Gui, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn)

        self.t1 = MyTrhead()
        self.t1.trigger.connect(self.dispaly_message)
        self.t1.start()
        print("thread: {}".format(self.t1.isRunning()))


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def dispaly_message(self, mystr):
        self.pushButton.setText(mystr)

    def btn(self):
        print("Return result to corresponding thread")



if "__main__" == __name__:
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Gui()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I wait in (multiple) threads for a user input?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, a `QThread` has an event loop that can process signals and slots. In your current implementation, you have unfortunately removed this behaviour by overriding `QThread.run`. If you restore it, you can get the behaviour you desire.

So if you can't override `QThread.run()`, how do you do threading in Qt? An alternative approach to threading is to put your code in a subclass of `QObject` and move that object to a standard `QThread` instance. You can then connect signals and slots together between the main thread and the `QThread` to communicate in both directions. This will allow you to implement your desired behaviour.

In the example below, I've started a worker thread which prints to the terminal, waits 2 seconds, prints again and then waits for user input. When the button is clicked, a second separate function in the worker thread runs, and prints to the terminal in the same pattern as the first time. Please note the order in which I use `moveToThread()` and connect the signals (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20752154/1994235)).

Code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import time

class MyWorker(QObject):

    wait_for_input = pyqtSignal()
    done = pyqtSignal()


    @pyqtSlot()
    def firstWork(self):
        print 'doing first work'
        time.sleep(2)
        print 'first work done'
        self.wait_for_input.emit()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def secondWork(self):
        print 'doing second work'
        time.sleep(2)
        print 'second work done'
        self.done.emit()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.initUi()
        self.setupThread()

    def initUi(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton('User input')
        self.button.setEnabled(False)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def enableButton(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(True)

    @pyqtSlot()    
    def done(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(False)

    def setupThread(self):
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = MyWorker()

        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.firstWork)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.worker.secondWork)
        self.worker.wait_for_input.connect(self.enableButton)
        self.worker.done.connect(self.done)

        # Start thread
        self.thread.start()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, one more question: How can I pass arguments from the function firstWork to the GUI and pass the result back to secondWork in case I have more than one of these worker threads? Think of, the function firstWork asks a question, passes this to the user and second work gets the answer?

Comment: Change the slot decorator to `@pyqtSlot( <arguments>)` followed by the same signature of the function that represents the slot `def firstwork(self, <argument variables>)`. For example `@pyqtSlot(int, str)` means that the slot requires 2 arguments (one of `int` and another of `str` type). The function that the slot decorator belongs to should look like `def firstWork(self, x, y)` with `x` being the `int` and `y` being the `str` pieces of data that the signal transports. You also have to change the signal received by that slot too: `mySignal = pyqtSignal(int, str)`.

Comment: @three_pineapples don't forget to connect `QThread.finished` signal to `self.worker.deleteLater` slot.

Comment: @rbaleksandar There isn't much point making that connection unless your thread is actually finishing (which requires you explicitly call `QThread.quit()` to end the event loop in this example)

Comment: @Maecky You can absolutely have multiple worker threads. Just create them in the same way as I've demonstrated, and connect the signals/slots as you wish. You can have as many `QThread` instances and `QObject` subclasses as you like, in any combination, with connections between all of them. Just be careful as making 3+ event loops consistent and interoperable can be challenging if you don't plan it out well.

Comment: @three_pineapples Not sure how it's in PyQt and if internally it gets take care of but in Qt C++ when you don't clean up your objects and also invoke quitting the thread you get a warning once you stop your application that a thread was destroyed prematurely. I'm also not sure whether moving a dynamically allocated `QObject` (even though it's PyQt underneath we have C++) to a `QThread` also makes the `QThread` parent to that object. If that's not the case we get a memory leak (again - underlying C++ talking here).