# PySide passing signals from QThread to a slot in another QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, pyside, qthread

> I solved my issue by moving the `mySubQThread` `run()` into the `myQThread` `run()`
>
> That said, I still would like to know why what I was attempting before didn't work.

I'm pretty new to threading. I am running into this issue and I think I may be approaching things wrong, anyway here goes. I am open to a different approach I know this may be a bit convoluted to follow.

I have a GUI that makes a new derived `QThread` lets call it `myQThread` within that thread, I am running through a process that creates another thread call it `mySubQThread` the issue I am having is as follows, I have signals defined in my GUI for example: `signalA = QtCore.Signal(int)` and a slot in `myQThread` The slot in the `mySubQThread` never seems to get the signal.

Here is a working example. (modified somewhat)

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import time



class myQThread(QtCore.QThread):
    myThreadSignal = QtCore.Signal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(myQThread, self).__init__(parent=parent)

    def run(self):
        self.subThread = mySubQThread(parent=self)
        self.myThreadSignal.connect(self.subThread.sub_thread_slot)
        self.myThreadSignal.connect(self.test_slot)
        print "starting subthread..."
        self.subThread.start()

        while self.subThread.isRunning():
            print "myQThread is alive!"
            time.sleep(1)
        print "myQThread exiting run..."
    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def my_thread_slot(self, a):
        print "1b) Made it here!"
        self.myThreadSignal.emit(a)

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def test_slot(self, a):
        print "2a) Made it here!"

class mySubQThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mySubSignalA = QtCore.Signal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(mySubQThread, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self._abort = False
    def run(self):
        #Do some processing
        #Wait for signal
        self._abort = False
        while not self._abort:
            print "mySubQThread is alive!"
            time.sleep(1)
        print "mySubQThread exiting run..."

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def sub_thread_slot(self, a):
        print "2b)Never make it here!"
        self._abort = True


class myWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    myWidgetSignal = QtCore.Signal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWidget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        #simple Widget to test this out....
        myLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.runButton = QtGui.QPushButton("run")
        self.runButton.clicked.connect(self.run_button_pressed)

        self.otherButton = QtGui.QPushButton("other")
        self.otherButton.clicked.connect(self.other_button_pressed)

        myLayout.addWidget(self.runButton)
        myLayout.addWidget(self.otherButton)

        self.setLayout(myLayout)
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def run_button_pressed(self):
        self.processThread = myQThread(self)
        self.myWidgetSignal.connect(self.processThread.my_thread_slot)
        self.myWidgetSignal.connect(self.test_slot)
        self.processThread.start()
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def other_button_pressed(self):
        self.myWidgetSignal.emit(1)

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def test_slot(self, a):
        print "1a) Made it here!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    myApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWin = myWidget()
    myWin.show()
    sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

Here is some sample output:

Note that if you change the line:

```
        self.subThread = mySubQThread(parent=self)
```

to

```
        self.subThread = mySubQThread(parent=None)
```

it stops complaining as it does in the sample output. neither shows that it makes it to 2B

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is myQThread(0x3c3faf0), parent's thread is QThread(0x2792548), current thread is myQThread(0x3c3faf0)
starting subthread...
myQThread is alive!mySubQThread is alive!

mySubQThread is alive!
myQThread is alive!
1b) Made it here!
2a) Made it here!
1a) Made it here!
```

Comment: Check the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#details just below the `WorkerThread` example. It provides some more explanation to why slots on QThreads don't work as one might expect.

Comment: @sebastian Thanks! I read that a couple times before, now it makes more sense.

Comment: I am now convinced to use the worker model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is because you have overridden `QThread.run()`. The `run` method by default contains an implementation that handles signal processing.

If you want to use signals/slots correctly you should subclass `QObject`, put your code in a method in there, and use `moveToThread()` to move the `QObject` to a base instance of `QThread` that you instantiate. You can then run your code by connecting your method to the `QThread.started` signal and then calling `thread.start()`

You can then repeat the creation of the child thread in a similar way, by putting that code in the method of the `QObject` previously created and launched in the thread. Signals and slots you connect there will be made between the thread and it's child thread correctly.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35534047/1994235) is a good example of proper communication between the main thread and a `QThread`, but you could easily extend it to between `QThreads`. Just modify the `MyWorker.firstWork()` method to launch a new `QThread` like is already done in the `setupThread` method.

Comment: I am now entirely convinced to use the worker model.