# Arduino Interfacing Within PyQt Widget

Tags: qt, python-3.x, arduino, pyqt

I have a PyQt program that hosts 2 widgets. The idea is to interface with my Arduino and display the Arduinos info in the program. I can't really attach my whole program but I'll give the highlights.

The Arduino takes a command over serial via `ser.write` and returns the subsequent information using `ser.read()`
So a simple function to continuously read the information from the Arduino would be

```
while True:
    ser.write(command.encode()
    time.sleep(.1)
    resp=ser.read()
    data=struct.unpack('<b',resp)
```

Now I want to use the information in `data` in my PyQt program however I cannot continuously run a loop in my Qt program because it will never display the program. I've tried using `QThread` by making a demo program however it crashes with error `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`. This is my demo program which should have similar functionality to the actual program.

```
import sys
import urllib
import urllib.request
import serial
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class CmdThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        BASIC="\x24\x4d\x3c\x00"

        self.ser=serial.Serial()
        #ser.port="COM12"
        self.ser.port='COM12'
        self.ser.baudrate=115200
        self.ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
        self.ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
        self.ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
        self.ser.timeout = 0
        self.ser.xonxoff = False
        self.ser.rtscts = False
        self.ser.dsrdtr = False
        self.ser.writeTimeout = 2
        self.ser.open()
        print('Initializing in 10 seconds...')
        time.sleep(10)

    def run(self):
        self.ser.write(self.BASIC.encode())
        time.sleep(0.1)
        resp=self.ser.read()
        datalength=struct.unpack('<b',resp)[0]
        data=self.ser.read(datalength+1)
        data=data[4:-1]
        temp=struct.unpack('<'+'h'*(int(len(data)/2)),data)
        self.ser.flushInput()
        self.ser.flushOutput()
        print((temp[0]/10,temp[1]/10,temp[2]))


class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.list_widget = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_cmd)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def start_cmd(self):
        downloader = CmdThread()
        downloader.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening or maybe a solution on how to incorporate the simpler `while` loop into a Qt widget? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to store a reference to the `QThread` so that it isn't garbage collected. Like this:

```
def start_cmd(self):
    self.downloader = CmdThread()
    self.downloader.start()
```

However be warned that clicking the button a second time will replace the original reference with a new one. And so the first thread may get garbage collected (which is probably fine if it is finished). You may want to eventually consider a more complex architecture where you always have a thread running and send commands from the main thread to the arduino thread via Qt signals/slots.

On another note, I assume at some point you will be using the results from the arduino to update a widget. Please make sure you don't directly access the widget from the thread (Qt GUI objects should only ever be accessed from the main thread). Instead you need to emit a signal (with a parameter that contains your data) from the thread which connects to a slot in the main thread. This slot is then able to safely access the GUI objects.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35534047/1994235) shows a more complex example with two way communication between the main thread and a worker thread (albeit without sending data along with the signal emission, but that is a reasonably trivial change)